# ArcGIS imagery analysis difference raster errors

Tags: arcgis-desktop, imagery, digital-image-processing

I have two DEM rasters from the USGS NED dataset.  One is from 2013 and one is from 2017, the extents should, and appear to, be 100% identical.  I ran the difference function on the ArcGIS Imagery Analysis window on these two rasters and got a resulting difference raster that appears to be accurate (via spot checking the input raster pixel values).  However when I zoom out past a certain point the difference raster symbology becomes incorrect & in contradiction of the identified pixel va
lues. (which remain accurate and in contradiction of the symbology)
The left image is at 1:250000 scale, the right 1:30000.  The error remains as I zoom out past 1:300000.  Classified in the attached as: Black = no difference (within a small tolerance), red = values decreased, green = increased.

Any ideas why might it be doing this and how can I get it to stop?  I'd like to get a single view of the entire difference raster but this problem is preventing that.  One input raster was in .img format, the other .flt, and both were single band & in the same unprojected GCS.

[image]

Comment: Rebuild your pyramids on the difference raster with the Nearest option http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m1000000 this will pick one of the cell values for the pyramid levels. What format is your difference raster? GRID, ERDAS IMG, GeoTIFF... other?